# Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit - Why only 3.7GB out of 4GB available?

Tags: ram, raspberrypi

I have Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, 4GB version.

4GB = 4 x 1024**3 = 4194304k

If I do the following...

`dmesg | grep Memory`

I get...

`[    0.000000] Memory: 3783876K/4050944K available (11772K kernel code, 1236K rwdata, 4244K rodata, 6144K init, 1072K bss, 201532K reserved, 65536K cma-reserved)`

I can't make any of the combinations of numbers add up to 4194304k?

And why `3783876k/4050944k` available, and not `???/4194304k`, i.e. the available memory out of 4GB?

Best wishes

Comment: That's a good point. No, I'm nit sure at all. I have been working on the basis that the minimum unit of memory is 1 byte (8 bits), and 1k = 1024 bytes, and 1M = 1024k, and  1G = 1024M. Please expand on 1GiB?

Comment: According to Google, for RAM purposes 1GiB is 1024**3 bytes, as per my question. So, I think the wording of my question is correct. Happy to proved otherwise.

Comment: Have you considered video ram?

Comment: No, that's another good point. I'm going to do bit more digging, especially where the video ram is allocated. Thanks.